# how do i fix SSH Permission denied?

Tags: openssh

I followed all the steps and created the `/home/dave/.ssh` folder. I then ran:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa –P ""
```

And got: `too many arguments`. I tried:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa –P
```

and it jumped back to the prompt.

I then tried:

```
$ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
cat: /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) your operating system and ii) the output of `ls -l /home/dave/.ssh` and `ls -ld /home/dave/.ssh`. Also, please explain what you are trying to do, what are you trying to set up, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the en dash `–` with `-`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

Comment: thank you very much....then it asked to put the file and i put it in both known_hosts.pub and     our identification has been saved in /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub       and  in  authorized_keys
It still says :   Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Comment: thank you very much....then it asked to put the file and i put it in both known_hosts.pub and  in  authorized_keys                                                                                                    
         and  i got:     
Your public key has been saved in /home/dave/.ssh/id_rsa.pub                                                                               
It still says :   Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Comment: @Dave this is a different issue. Please ask a new question, but this time make sure to explain what you are trying to do and what operating system you are using. Don't just list the commands you ran, the commands don't do what you want so they're probably the wrong commands, but we can't help you if you don't tell us what you _want_ the commands to do.

Comment: Increasing the verbosity of the SSH daemon (and the client) should yield information as to why it's saying denied.

Comment: well, i read somewhere that SSH was easier to connect my computers at home. But that was a joke.  so i gave up on that option.